# Avoid Duplication or Error When Updating Form in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, forms, laravel-5, sql-update

I have 2 tables `beneficiaries` and `addresses` joined with relation `beneficiary_id` as foreign key while each beneficiary record should have 1 address only.

The records are duplicated or fails to insert `request()` in the second table.

When I use the below code the records are duplicated

```
public function update(UpdateBeneficiaryRequest $request, Beneficiary $beneficiary, Address $address)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('beneficiary_edit'), 403);

    $beneficiary->update($request->all());

    // $address->update($request->all());

    $address->fill([
        'beneficiary_id'    => $beneficiary->id,
        'country'           => request('country'),
        'state'             => request('state'),
        'district'          => request('district'),
        'town'              => request('town'),
        'street'            => request('street'),
        'building'          => request('building'),
        'nearby'            => request('nearby')
    ]);

    //->where('id',$id);
    //$address->save();

    $beneficiary->addresses()->save($address);

    return redirect()->route('admin.beneficiaries.index');
}
```

However when I change the code to get all requests I get an error

```
public function update(UpdateBeneficiaryRequest $request, Beneficiary $beneficiary, Address $address)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('beneficiary_edit'), 403);

    $beneficiary->update($request->all());

    $address->update($request->all());

    //->where('id',$id);
    //$address->save();

    $beneficiary->addresses()->save($address);

    return redirect()->route('admin.beneficiaries.index');
}
```

Error Message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'country' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `addresses` (`beneficiary_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2019-12-02 02:07:27, 2019-12-02
>   02:07:27))

In the second option the request aren't sent according to table structure

beneficiaries table structure

[image: beneficiaries table structure]

addresses table structure
[image: addresses table structure]

How to avoid records duplication while updating form and get all request to be inserted in the right tables.

I've also used `update()` and `updateOrCreate()` functions however both ended in the same result

Please note I'm currently using 2 tables while the target to use 5 tables for 1 form.

EDIT: Fields are mandatory can't be NULL

Added the UpdateBeneficiaryRequest class

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Beneficiary;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateBeneficiaryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return \Gate::allows('beneficiary_edit');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'      => [ 'required',],
            'lname'     => [ 'required',],
            'father'    => [ 'required',],
            'mother'    => [ 'required',],
            'dob'       => [ 'required',],
            'phone'     => [ 'required',],
            'record_no' => [ 'required',],
            'country'   => [ 'required',],
            'state'     => [ 'required',],
            'district'  => [ 'required',],
            'town'      => [ 'required',],
            'street'    => [ 'required',],
            'building'  => [ 'required',],
            'nearby'    => [ 'required',],

        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your country column is set to not null.

`insert into addresses (beneficiary_id, updated_at, created_at) values (1, 2019-12-02 02:07:27, 2019-12-02 02:07:27)`

the above query is failing because of that. It will fail with `updateOrCreate()` as it will try to add in case it does not exist.

You have to make all the column null if they are not mandatory.

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention they're mandatory fields can't remain null. It's the edit section meaning the records already in database and fetched for view

Comment: ```updateOrCreate(
    $request->all(),
    ['beneficiary_id' => 1]
);``` try this.

Comment: I tried this before however it's duplicating the data and not updating the right row

Comment: You have to query before update. ```DB::table('addresses')->where('beneficiary_id', 1)->update($request->all());```

Comment: Thank you but this returned the same error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'country' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `addresses` (`beneficiary_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2019-12-02 03:33:37, 2019-12-02 03:33:37))`. I have updated my question with UpdateBeneficiaryRequest class

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate your form before saving the data to the database. And it looks like you are using a custom validation class called `UpdateBeneficiaryRequest`. In these class you have to set a validation on the field that you want to be unique on the data base. See example below. We want to make sure that the beneficiary_id is unique inside the  address table.

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
      'beneficiary_id' => 'required|unique:address,beneficiary_id,'.$this->address->id,
  ];
}
```

Comment: I've updated my custom class code you can check. `$this->address->id` is not a defined variable there

Comment: In the both `beneficiaries` and `addresses` the `id` should be unique while `beneficiary_id` should be automatic relation between both tables which works well on `create` but not on `update`

Answer (score 0):

After Struggling I had to go to the main process...

```
public function update(UpdateBeneficiaryRequest $request, Beneficiary $beneficiary, Address $address)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('beneficiary_edit'), 403);

    $beneficiary->update($request->all());

    $address = Address::find($beneficiary->id);
    $address = Address::where('beneficiary_id', '=', $beneficiary->id)->first();
    $address->country   = $request->country;
    $address->state     = $request->state;
    $address->district  = $request->district;
    $address->town      = $request->town;
    $address->street    = $request->street;
    $address->building  = $request->building;
    $address->nearby    = $request->nearby;
    $address->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.beneficiaries.index');
}
```

Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

The Simple solution for this simple problem..

your migration file.

```
public function up(){
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('address')->unique();
}
```

by adding unique(), it will allow only unique values in the table, try to re-migrate your table with this function.